# VB6 SQL Script Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword

Tags: sql, vb6, foxpro

I am writing a SQL insert statement into Foxpro when I copy the SQL from the VB6 code in inserts into Foxpro no issue. When I take that same SQL and copy it to a test program it inserts no issue. When I execute the SQL in the original program I get "Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword".

cnSO is just the connection object I used the same connection string in the test program as I did in the live program.

```
insertSQL = "insert into soordeht (" & insertFields & ") values (" & Replace(insertData, Chr(34), "'") & ")"
Debug.Print insertSQL
'Debug.Print (insertFields)
'Debug.Print (insertData)
cnSO.Execute ("set null off")
cnSO.Execute (insertSQL)
```

This is the outputted SQL

```
insert into soordeht (ordnum,number,orddate,time,ordtype,origin,name,address1,credline1,address2,city,state,zip,country,contact,tcode_1,tcode_2,tcode_3,agginvoice,division,discperc,taxzone,shipcode,shipname,shipadd1,shipadd2,shipcity,shipst,shipzip,shipctry,shipphone,shiparea,dist_ctr,store_no,dept_num,consacct,shipaymeth,billname,billadd1,billadd2,billcity,billst,billzip,billphone,custponum,cred1or2,shipvia,termcode,whnum,prtstatus,invoiceprt,orderprt,packprt,userid,slpcode,slpcomm,slpperc,comtype,compaid,comchgpcnt,comchgdays,comchgwarn,deldate,fax,areafax,source,trans_num,cross_dock,shipref,numlabels,paytype,shipstatus,status,fre_tax,trackingno,comment) values ("20026513","02658",{^2017-01-20},"11:37PM","S","L","KIDS ROOM, INC","GARY AND ED GOTLIEB","GARY AND ED GOTLIEB","5801 WESTHEIMER","HOUSTON","TX","77005","","GARY AND ED","00","00","00",.F.,"00",0,"","70290","C&S WHOLESALE GROCERS","OLD FERRY ROAD","","BRATTLEBORO","VT","05301","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","722480","N ","","CC","DEF","Y",.T.,.T.,.T.,"SUP","HOU",5,100,"",0,0,0,0,{^2017-02-21},"","","ED^","35417","","",0,0,"Y","S","N","","")
```

Comment: Can you clarify where it is working and not working?

Comment: That's the weird thing it works consistently with out issue. It is just in this one case with the one customers data that it does not work. I would like to blame the data but if it were the data it would not work when ran in Foxpro or the test program.

Comment: Odds are a constraint or data type violation is taking place.  Don't assume that because it works on one db, it must work on another.  Data types are sometimes vendor specific and can be very subtle.   The easiest way to locate the problem is to use null values ( or known acceptable values ) in all of the suspect fields.  If that works, re-introduce your intended values into 1/2 of those fields.  If you get a failure, its is one of THOSE fields.   if not, its in the other half of the fields.  divide and conquer...

Comment: Try losing the carat from your orddate. {^2017-01-20} should be {2017-01-20}

Comment: Actually, for VFP, the carat says that it's in YMD format. Otherwise, the SET DATE setting would be assumed. So, the carat is correct.

Answer (score 0):

in VFP the `replace` function it's used to fill a given field of a table, IMHO i think that you want to replace the `"` with `'`, if that, you should use `STRTRAN(string to transform, string to seek, string to replace)`:

```
insertSQL = "insert into soordeht (" & insertFields & ") values (" & STRTRAN(insertData, '"', "'") & ")"
```

Note that the second parameter is `"` enclosed in `'   '`, and the third paremeter is `'` enclosed in `"   "`, that's because you need to enclosure the 'enclosure' in different way, or do as you do first, calling the `CHR(34)` function.